# LibGdx Weird Effect after Removing glClear

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I wanted to remove glClear so I could animate an object and as it moves across the screen it shows the images as it animates that wouldn't have if I included glClear. It worked on the emulator but when I put in on my phone it does that. I figured it must be a dpi thing, is there anything I can do?

[screenshot of my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPvO4.png)

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    fbo.begin();
    fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
    if (!deckBuilder.isPlayingAnimation()){
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(39/255f, 39/255f, 198/255f, 1);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    if (timer.getUserObject().equals("reset"))
    {
        timer.setUserObject("");
        totalTime = 0;
    }
    if (minutes < 60 || countTime) {
        deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime(); //You might prefer getRawDeltaTime()

        totalTime += deltaTime; //if counting down

        minutes = ((int) totalTime) / 60;
        seconds = ((int) totalTime) % 60;
        timer.setText(("" + (100 + minutes)).substring(1) + ":" + ("" + (100 + seconds)).substring(1));
    }
    else
    {
        if (!setConstantTime)
        {
            setConstantTime = true;
            timer.setText("#!#%&");
        }
    }
    fbo.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you're creating a FrameBuffer in the render loop. Incidentally, you are leaking these once per frame. FrameBuffer must always be disposed before you lose the reference.

On your emulator the way memory was recycled must have resulted in you accidentally getting what you wanted. But right now you are drawing to the previous frame's `fbo` followed by overwriting the reference with a newly allocated FrameBuffer every frame that I assume you are then drawing onto the screen.